# Rails form getting submitted very oddly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the blelow form select

```
<%= f.select(:title, options_for_select([['Pick a reason',{:value => 0}],['Title 2', {:value => 1}], ['Title 3', {:value => 3}])) %>
```

So when somebody picks one of the three options from the dropdown, using jquery i am rendering one of the three in the text box.

```
<%= f.text_area :text , :rows => 10, :class=>"selectInput", :id=>"0", :style=>"display:none;", :value=>" text for pick reason"%>

<%= f.text_area :text , :rows => 10, :class=>"selectInput", :id=>"1", :style=>"display:none;", :value=>" text for title 1"%>

<%= f.text_area :text , :rows => 10, :class=>"selectInput", :id=>"2", :style=>"display:none;", :value=>" text for title 2"%>
```

But what happens is no matter what option is being selected, the last text_area entry gets saved in the db. In this case its

```
<%= f.text_area :text , :rows => 10, :class=>"selectInput", :id=>"2", :style=>"display:none;", :value=>" text for title 2"%>
```

How do i avoid that ? And make sure what is shown in the screen is what gets saved to the db.

Also here is my jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bashing_title').change(function(){
        $(".selectInput").hide();
        $("#"+this.selectedIndex).show();
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are hiding several of the textarea's visually, this doesn't prevent them all from being submitted - and the last value to be serialized will be used by Rails.

Instead, you should have a single textbox, and modify the content depending on the selected option:

```
<% text_values = {"text0" => "text for pick reason", 
                  "text1" => "text for title1", 
                  "text2" => "text for title2" } %>
<%= f.text_area :text , :rows => 10, :class=>"selectInput", 
                :style=>"display:none;", :value => "", 
                :data => text_values %>

<script>
   $(function(){
     $('#bashing_title').change(function(){
       var textArea = $(".selectInput");
       textArea.show().val(textArea.data('text' + this.selectedIndex));
     });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: its not loading textbox to enter any text.

Comment: The textbox is initially hidden - it only displays when you select an option.  If you don't want this, just remove the `:style => 'display:none;'` from the declaration.

Comment: Hmm, can you post the HTML for the textbox and select list that is being rendered?

Comment: i am sorry, i messed up the js.

Comment: the array is not getting rendered fine to automatically populate the text box.

Comment: Updated to avoid using an array - I'm not sure why, but the array isn't being parsed properly.  Using individual keys seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `placeholder` in `textarea` instead of `value`?

```
<%= f.text_area :text , :rows => 10, :class=>"selectInput", :id=>"2", :style=>"display:none;", :placeholder=>" text for title 2"%>
```

If the problem still pertains, it may be because those fields still exist in your DOM. Try modifying your jQuery code to `remove()` those fields which are not to be shown instead of `hide()`

Comment: i need to have a placeholder, part of ux and no `remove` doesnt work.

Comment: need to have placeholder? Logically, must be used for the purpose shown above. Do you have to retain it for some other use?

Comment: i am sorry i meant i need to have a value and not placeholder (little stressed out :P)

Comment: if i do it by having placeholder. it submits an empty form

Comment: then, the problem must naturally be there in your jQuery code. The last textarea must somehow be still there in your DOM after you `select` from dropdown. Please check.

Comment: i am unable to figure it out. tried using `remove` it but it removes the entire making inaccessible to load the text box

Comment: Naturally. Calling `.remove()` first will delete all text areas. That's why I asked you to modify your jQuery based on your logic and elements. Try out with removing [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead of all textareas at once.